# ¿Cómo paso la función de className a NavLink?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, react-router-dom

Sucede que estoy usando React Router v6 y styled components en mi proyecto. Quiero aplicarle estilos a un elemento NavLink del react router usando styled components, pero también quiero poder agregarle clases 'dinámicas' usando el prop isActive que proporciona React Router cuando le pasamos una función al className (quiero cambiar los estilos del link dependiendo de si está activo o no). Cuando le paso dicha función directamente al className del NavLink todo funciona como debería; pero si se la paso al componente que envuelve a NavLink para aplicarle los estilos (LLamémoslo NavbarLink) sucede que en vez de ejecutar la función, me agrega la función en texto como si fuera una clase, lo cual es totalmente erróneo a lo que yo quiero hacer.

Sin usar NavbarLink (o sea, usando directamente NavLink de react router) funciona perfectamente: Cuando estoy en DC, su botón está en rojo y marvel en azul, y viceversa cuando estoy en Marvel.

```js
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavbarLink } from './NavbarLink';


export const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">

            <NavLink to="/marvel" className={({ isActive }) => `btn btn-${isActive ? 'danger' : 'primary'}`}>
                Marvel
            </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/dc" className={({ isActive }) => `btn btn-${isActive ? 'danger' : 'primary'}`}
            >
                DC
            </NavLink>
        </nav >
    )
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando uso el NavbarLink (que simplemente aplica estilos al NavLink) los resultados no son los mismos:

```js
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavbarLink } from './NavbarLink';


export const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <NavbarLink to="/marvel" className={({ isActive }) => `btn btn-${isActive ? 'danger' : 'primary'}`}>
                Marvel
            </NavbarLink>

            <NavbarLink to="/dc" className={({ isActive }) => `btn btn-${isActive ? 'danger' : 'primary'}`}
            >
                DC
            </NavbarLink>
        </nav >
    )
}
```

```js
//NavbarLink.js  : Simplemente agrega un color de fondo rosa, a modo de ejemplo

import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const NavbarLink = styled(NavLink)`
    background-color: pink;
`;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Noten cómo le agrega la función como si fuera un texto, en vez de ejecutarla:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

He logrado resolver la cuestión. No sé por qué exactamente la className se agrega como texto en vez de ejecutarse la función. En todo caso, creé un componente que devuelve un NavLink, y recibe automáticamente los parámetros to, children, className y el resto de propiedades (...props) Y las aplica al NavLink (Literalmente estoy devolviendo el NavLink). Luego vinculo ese navlink al componente estilizado(styled(Link)) y ya recibe la función de className y la ejecuta de la forma usual

```js
import { NavLink as NavbarLinkRouterDom } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Link = function ({ to, children, className, ...props }) {
    return (
        <NavbarLinkRouterDom
            {...props}
            className={({ isActive }) =>
                `${className} ${isActive ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-danger'}`
            }
            to={to}
        >
            {children}
        </NavbarLinkRouterDom>
    );
};

export const NavbarLink = styled(Link)`
    padding: 2rem;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve ese problema y lo solucioné así:

```
const active = {
    color: 'red',
}

const disactive = {
    default: {
        color: "#eee"
    },
    Hovered: {
        color: 'red'
    }

}
```

y después en el NavLink:

```
<NavLink to="ruta" style={({ isActive }) => isActive ? active : disactive}>
    link 
</NavLink>
```